# Understanding Quantile-Quantile Plot of my Signal

Tags: statistics, probability-distribution-function

I have computed the Q-Q plot of my dataset, which is a recording from a brain signal, and it shows a curious left and right skewness displacement, and I was wondering if this is any other distribution that I would infer from the graph. Since I am not expert in this area, I am a bit lost understanding the Q-Q plot. Would you give me a hand on this? Below you find the signal in time representation and the Q-Q plot.

A bit of description about my signal. It corresponds to the extracellular recording of a microelectrode introduced in a brain tissue. I record the signal using a particular instrument and then, I have already studied the main aspects in time and frequency domain. At this point, I am trying to perform a test for normality and variance in order to determine which statistic parameters are the best for evaluating classification algorithms over this dataset.

[image]

Below, you can see the probability density function of the dataset that I have computed with numpy.

[image]

And below, the Q-Q plot that I have computed with scipy stats functionality. Note that my dataset is very large, I have approximately 3,600,000 samples for this signal.

[image]

Comment: the theoretical model fits *surprisingly well* in the region between roughly -2.1 and +2.0. As a matter of fact, though, your observation seems to have a heavily scaled distribution of the values in the theoretical model. Which would suggest that either your theoretical model is explicitly only meant to describe a limited region, or your measurement becomes unreliable, physically, at the edges. Since we know neither your model nor what you're actually measuring, and how ("brain signal" is ... anything, from EEG voltages, or estimated currents,  to serotonin levels, to…): can't make assessment.

Comment: now, I'm very far removed from neurology, so I'm not familiar with any of the models for the signals you might be observing. It's worth noting though that it's usually important to understand the limitations of the model, so describing the model and *why*/on what basis it is used to model the phenomenon you're observing might be a good first step!

Comment: (also, grumpy thesis advisor here: the top plot has no axis labels whatsoever. It's honestly a bit useless to explain your question as it currently stands – but it might be super useful once you explain what you're observing, and what the model models.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are completely right, I just edited the post with the figures labelled and a bit more of information about the signals. However, I would like to highlight that where the signal comes from is not the main issue for this analysis but understanding the distribution of my data in the Q-Q plot. I would like to raise a question. I know from my data, that most of the signal values are around 10 to 30 uV, because they corresponds to the noise floor, so my dataset doesn't strictly matches a normal distribution, but a plateau. Am I correct on this interpretation?

Comment: making assumptions on the distribution without understanding what the signal signifies is a recipe for misinterpretation, though :) You'd need to preclude other effects affecting the normality of the distribution before you assume it to be a good classification feature. In this case, it's pretty clear that the data is *not* expected to be normal – it's bursty, and seems to have two different ranges in which it is more uniformly than normally distributed, depending on whether you're currently in a burst or not. So, assuming normality seems to be an odd choice!

Comment: "doesn't strictly matches a normal distribution": If the noise is uncorrelated, it can't transform a normal distribution into a "plateau". You just have no reason to assume normality for your data!

Comment: And: having non-normally distributed data is a *gift*, not a curse. It's much easier to check whether some non-normal distribution is present in the presence of normal noise.

Comment: I understand your point about the signal source, I reckon that it's just that not many people are familiar with this signal typology and, sometimes explaining all the sources of noise and some features it's a bit long. Regarding the distribution. I understand from your comment above that the signal follows a normal distribution within [-2, +2], however, what kind of information does the tails give? I mean, how can I interpretate that in a physical point of view, or let's say, electric perspective

Comment: "non-normally distributed data is a gift, not a curse" Sure! I know that I am not trying to corroborate or trying to force the result, I just need to formally defend my hypothesis for stating a result later on. From a not-normal distribution, I can run a non-parametric statistical analysis and extract some significant information.

Comment: It does **not** follow a normal distribution if it only looks normal within a small range. What you should interpret is that your signal is not normally distributed :)

Comment: These plots suggest a heavy tail distribution.

Comment: That does not ask my question about the tail. I know that if the whole data set does not follow a normal distribution it cannot be interpreted as it is. But what does the tails represent? What does a heavy tail distribution mean?

Comment: @GGChe read [Wikipedia about heavy-tailed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution). About "what does the tail represent?", I don't know, that's your research. Your data follows a distribution, yes, but it is not necessarily a well-known one, nor must it have a closed form pdf. If I were you, I would check the plots of the data versus many known heavy-tailed distributions to see which one is the best to *approximate* the data. If I were lucky to find one, I would feed it into my classification algorithm and pray to God to let it work.

Comment: Ok good, it sounds fair. At least I know that I cannot assume normality and that it looks like a heavy-tailed distribution. I will continue researching in that direction. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I think it would make sense to start by manually segmenting your data into times where there seems to be activity/spikes and those with only low-amplitude signal (noise? not sure!), and make conditional PDFs for both cases.

Comment: That would make sense. Actually, they are very differente in the frequency domain and it would make same to be similar statistically talking, in fact, there is a lot of similarities between frequency and statistical study. I will do it again with this approach and see the differences!